# SQL group by coalesce not working as expected

Tags: mysql, sql

I have following MySQL table (`images`):

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| id | gallery_id | path                                                                                                    |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| 58 |       NULL | 58.jpg 
| 59 |       NULL | 59.jpg 
| 66 |          9 | 9-001.jpg 
| 67 |          9 | 9-002.jpg 
| 68 |         10 | 10-001.jpg 
| 69 |         10 | 10-002.jpg 
...
```

I want to select rows where gallery_id is null or group it by gallery_id if it not null.
So expected result is:

```
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| id | gallery_id | path                                                                                                    |
+----+------------+-----------------------+
| 58 |       NULL | 58.jpg 
| 59 |       NULL | 59.jpg 
| 66 |          9 | 9-001.jpg 
| 68 |         10 | 10-001.jpg 
...
```

I tried to use `coalesce` function to achieve this result:

```
select * from `images` group by coalesce(gallery_id, id);
```

But it returns only rows where `gallery_id` is null. 
Tell me please what am I doing wrong? Thanks in advance.

Comment: You query is properly working. http://sqlfiddle.com/#!9/e85a45/1

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your request doesn't make sense.  `GROUP BY` with `SELECT *` is non-sensical, because it is unclear where most of the column values come from.

You seem to want prioritization . . . one row for each `NULL` and then one for each gallery.

I would suggest:

```
select i.*
from images i
where i.gallery_id is null or
      i.id in (select min(i2.id) from images i2 group by i2.gallery_id);
```

As a bonus, this is standard SQL and should work in any database.

Answer (score 1):

You could use a when in with subselect and group by

```
select * from `images`
where (gallery_id, id ) in (select gallery_id, min(id) 
                             from `images`
                             where gallery_id is not null
                             group by gallery_id)
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT * FROM `images` where gallery_id is not null group by gallery_id 
UNION
SELECT * FROM `images` where gallery_id is null
```